# Getting error when changing sheet names

Tags: vba

I am running the below code and it works well - it creates my file with the name specified in Cell B1 on Sheet1, but when I name my sheet something else (example FileNames) it gives me an error.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Betty_smith\Desktop\VBA\" &
Replace(Sheet1.Range("B1").Text, ".txt", "") & ".txt", True)

End Sub
```

This is the code giving me an error:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\iwona_ring\Desktop\VBA\" & 
Replace(Names.Range("B1").Text, ".txt", "") & ".txt", True)

End Sub
```

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace(Sheet1.Range("B1").Text, ".txt", "") & ".txt", True)
```

Looks like you're using the Sheet's codename (shown in the VB editor Project explorer window; initially it's the same as the sheet tab name, but is not changed when you change the tab name)

update to:

```
Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Text, ".txt", "") & ".txt", True)
```

Then update the "Sheet1" to whatever is the new sheet name...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 concepts:

- name -> used when you write `Worksheets("Names").Range(...)`
- code name -> used when you write `Names.Range(...)`

Initially they have the same value:

- name = Sheet1
- code name = Sheet1

But after you **rename** the tab, those names won't have the same value. The **name** will be **changed**, but the **code name** remains **the same**:

- name = Names
- code name = Sheet1

  (so, your code fails because there is no code name = Names)

To check that those values are different, **right click on a tab** > **View code** > in the top-left corner see something like this:

- Sheet1 (Names)
- Sheet2 (Sheet2)
- Sheet3 (Sheet3)

[image: name vs code name]